# Sum of values under a merged Cell

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to get the Sum for the following formatted spreadsheet:

```
|PIZZA |ABC |21 |
|      |GHT |12 |
|      |ERT |45 |
|      |DFT |2  |=21+12+45+2
|EGGS  |GTD |96 |
|      |YHJ |5  |
|      |PHJ |78 |=96+5+78
```

The list continues for 1000+ items with variable amount of LOT#

Answer (score 4):

This solution uses a helper column D (it could be hidden, or placed far to the right on the sheet).

Formula in D2: `=if(len(A2), C2, C2+D1)`, then dragged down the row. This computes a cumulative sum, restarting every time there is an entry in A column.

Formula in E2: `=if(len(A3), D2,)`, then dragged down the row. This only hides the intermediate results of the calculation of the cumulative sums.

```
+---+-------+---+---+----+----+
|   |   A   | B | C | D  | E  |
+---+-------+---+---+----+----+
| 1 |       |   |   |    |    |
| 2 | pizza | q | 2 |  2 |    |
| 3 |       | w | 3 |  5 |    |
| 4 |       | e | 4 |  9 |    |
| 5 |       | r | 5 | 14 | 14 |
| 6 | eggs  | d | 6 |  6 |    |
| 7 |       | f | 7 | 13 |    |
| 8 |       | g | 8 | 21 | 21 |
| 9 | ham   | h | 1 |  1 |    |
+---+-------+---+---+----+----+
```

Answer (score 3):

This solution uses an array formula and named ranges:

**Formula**

```
=ArrayFormula(
 IFERROR(
  POWER(
   POWER(
    MMULT(
     TRANSPOSE(
      N(
       vlookup(ROW(Categories),FILTER(ROW(Categories),LEN(Categories)),1)
       =
       TRANSPOSE(
        vlookup(ROW(Categories),FILTER(ROW(Categories),LEN(Categories)),1)
       )  
     )
     *
     Values
    ),
   SIGN(ROW(Categories))
  )
  *
  N({LEN(Offset(Categories,1,,ROWS(Categories)-1))>=1;1}),
  -1),
 -1)
 )
)
```

**Example**

Set Categories as the name of A1:A7 and Values as the name of B2:B7. Then add the above formula to C1. The result will look like the following:

```
+---+--------+----+----+
|   |   A    | B  | C  |
+---+--------+----+----+
| 1 | orange | 20 |    |
| 2 |        |  7 |    |
| 3 |        | 20 | 47 |
| 4 | apple  | 13 |    |
| 5 |        |  2 | 15 |
| 6 | banana | 17 |    |
| 7 |        | 16 | 33 |
+---+--------+----+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try also this 2 formulas:

## 1

`=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(
    SPLIT(
     JOIN("",
      ArrayFormula(
       REPT(
        FILTER(Categories,Categories<>"")&"-",
        len(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(JOIN(",",Categories)&",","[A-Za-z]+","-"),"-")))
       )
      )
     ),"-"
    )
   ))`

## 2

`=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(ROW(Categories),
   QUERY({ROW(Categories),Categories},"select * where Col2 <> ''"),
  2))`

---

## Profit

1. They both use original array only 3 times.
2. ArrayFormulas
3. Second is shorter